# Nginx proxy_ssl_certificate not working as expected

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

I'm using nginx as a proxy to a backend server. 
The backend server is also using nginx and enforcing client certificate authentication using the `ssl_client_certificate` and `ssl_verify_client` directives.

In my nginx server I set the following:

```
location  /proxy {
    proxy_pass             https://www.backend.com;

    proxy_set_header       X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header       X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header       X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/cert/client.crt;
    proxy_ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/cert/client.key;
}
```

according to [the nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl_certificate).

However, the backend is still responding with a 400 reponse code `"No required SSL certificate was sent"`.

Note that when issuing requests to the backend server using wget with the client certificate, I get a valid 200 OK response:

```
wget --certificate=/etc/nginx/cert/client.crt --private-key=/etc/nginx/cert/client.key https://www.backend.com
```

What am I missing in my nginx configuration?

Answer (score 8):

This [post](https://www.robertkehoe.com/2016/07/nginx-proxy-pass-resolving-no-required-ssl-certificate-was-sent/) seemed to solve this problem for me.

I had to add the following setting to get things working for me.

```
proxy_ssl_server_name      on;
```